# ODBC, MSSQL, FreeTDS inner join not returning data from second table

Tags: php, sql-server, inner-join, freetds, unixodbc

I have FreeTDS installed on an Ubuntu 14.04 server.  I am connecting to the MSSQL database as follows:

```
$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=<IP Address>; Port=1433; Database=db_name; UID=user; PWD=password;');
```

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT c.*, ct.*  
FROM Committee AS c
INNER JOIN CommitteeType as ct on c.CommitteeTypeID=ct.CommitteeTypeID
WHERE CommitteeID=$committee_id
```

Then I am running:

```
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
```

The resulting array is very much what would be expected except that the values from the CommitteeType table are all empty.  When I run the exact same query in Navicat on the database I get values for everything from the second table.

Is there something buggy about this driver?

I have tried many variations on the query syntax without any difference in output.  It appears that I can never get values from an inner joined table regardless of which tables I am querying.

Anyone see anything I am missing or have experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there are issues with odbc.  I am now successfully using dblib instead.

Here is the full recipe for anyone that wants to get this up and running:

These were the original directions I followed

1. Install the packages freetds-bin, freetds-common, tdsodbc, odbcinst, php5-odbc and unixodbc. This provides the libraries you need.
2. Copy the contents of /usr/share/doc/freetds-common/examples/odbcinst.ini into /etc/odbcinst.ini. This registers the FreeTDS driver with the ODBC layer.
3. Restart your webserver to load the ODBC module into PHP.

Then connected with:

```
<?php
try
{
  $db = new PDO('odbc:Driver=FreeTDS; Server=hostname_or_ip; Port=port; Database=database_name; UID=username; PWD=password;');
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
  die("Unable to open database.<br />Error message:<br /><br />$exception.");
}
echo '<h1>Successfully connected!</h1>';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

To correct the issue I was having I installed:

php5-sybase (ie sudo apt-get install php5-sybase)

Then connected as such:

```
<?php
  try {
    $hostname = "myhost";
    $port = 10060;
    $dbname = "tempdb";
    $username = "dbuser";
    $pw = "password";
    $db = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  }
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
  die("Unable to open database.<br />Error message:<br /><br />$exception.");
}
echo '<h1>Successfully connected!</h1>';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```